# VBA webResponse Response.data getting error when changing type from "Dictionary" to "collection"

Tags: vba, scripting.dictionary

Here is the problem : I have the following code

```
Dim Client As New WebClient
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Dim Response As WebResponse
    
Dim responseData As Scripting.Dictionary
    
Request.UserAgent = VBA.Environ("USERNAME")
Request.AddHeader "AuthToken", m_token
Request.AddHeader "APIKey", m_key
Request.Method = WebMethod.HttpPost
    
Dim Auth As New HttpBasicAuthenticator
Auth.Setup "username", "Password"
Set Client.Authenticator = Auth
    
Dim Body As New Dictionary
If condition1 Then
        Body.Add "status", "open"
Else
        Body.Add "status", "closed"
End If
    
Client.BaseUrl = server_api & "Tasks/" & m_id
    
Set Request.Body = Body
Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
    
If (Response.StatusCode = Ok) Then
        Debug.Print TypeName(Response.Data) 'returns Dictionary
        Set responseData = Response.Data '.Item(1)
        Debug.Print "ID: " & responseData("id")
        Debug.Print "message: " & responseData("message")
End If
```

The request is executed with success, the program has no errors, and the `Response.data` has the typename `Dictionary`, but message is :

> 'statut' doesn't exist in table

So I tried to fix this by changing the "status" name to the required "tableColunm" which have int32 as type in the database.

The changes applied are in the following code with results on comments:

```
    If condition1 Then
        Body.Add "tableColunm", 1 'I tried also with "1"
    Else
        Body.Add "tableColunm", 2 ' I tried also with "2"
    End If        Client.BaseUrl = server_api & "Tasks/" & m_id
    
    Set Request.Body = Body
    Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)
    
    If (Response.StatusCode = Ok) Then
        Debug.Print TypeName(Response.Data) 'returns Collection
        Set responseData = Response.Data '.Item(1) ' error here, and the program crashed
        Debug.Print "ID: " & responseData("id")
        Debug.Print "message: " & responseData("message")
    End If
```

Now the typename of `Response.data` is collection, and I think this is the reason why the program crashes

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention what library you're using for this - `HttpBasicAuthenticator` for example is not native to VBA....

Comment: It uses `RestSharp` library.

Comment: Isn't that a .NET library?  Not VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after adding this

```
For Each elt In Response.Data
    Debug.Print TypeName(elt)
Next
```

The loop is executed only one time, outputting `Dictionary`. That's mean that in the second case, the dictionary is encapsulated on a collection

So I worked with `elt` and this solves my problem